# S3 Asset uploading is hanging

Tags: s3

I have setup a barebones install, and authenticated my bucket using the root user S3 credentials (just for now). Assets do not upload. I read a similar question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/s3-asset-uploading-hangs) where the answer was that the response was being blocked by a firewall. I have tested on other connections and the issue wasn't resolved. Craft support suggested that I could edit some code on craft/app/lib/S3.PHP around line 771 but I'm not sure how to go about solving.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that Frankfurt and London are not currently supported S3 bucket locations in Craft CMS v2.6.2956. Switching to Ireland solved my issue.

Comment: How did you find out about this? Is it ever going to be supported in craft2?

Comment: Frankfurt and London are quite new S3 bucket locations. It will be supported but they have only just come out.

Comment: I asked in Craft Slack recently, these buckets will not be supported in Craft 2. Though they will be in Craft 3.